# Exception handling in Procedure with nested functions in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have an pl/sql procedure as mentioned below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_affectedCircle
(v_affected_circle IN v_circle.circle_code%type)
IS
    v_circle_id  NUMBER;

BEGIN
        v_circle_id := get_circleID(v_affected_circle);
        INSERT INTO vf_affected_circle (affected_circle) 
        values (v_circle_id);

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20101, 'Problem in loading Affected Circle data');
END;
/
```

First I was checking the particular data v_affected_circle is available in circle_code column in vf_circle table using function get_circleID and returning the circle_id associated with circle_code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_circleID 
( v_circle_code  vf_circle.circle_code%TYPE)
RETURN vf_circle.circle_id%TYPE
IS
    return_value  vf_circle.circle_id%TYPE; 
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        SELECT circle_id INTO return_value
        FROM vf_circle
        WHERE circle_code = v_circle_code;
   END;
   RETURN return_value;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20102, 'Circle Code is wrong or not available');
END get_circleID;
/
```

I am tying to raise user exception **(-20102, 'Circle Code is wrong or not same as records')** in the function **get_circleID**  when the data is not available for the provided data **v_affected_circle**. This function is called from procedure add_affectedCircle

I am trying to raise another user exception if some problem happens in loading data into particular table vf_affected_circle as **(-20102, 'Problem in loading Affected Circle data')** .

Now the problem is I try to run the procedure **add_affectedCircle** with wrong values, I am getting exception only from procedure not from the function. Also I am seeing other exceptions which I am unable to handle and suppress it.

Now I am getting exception like this

```
BEGIN add_affectedCircle(69,'ODI:ASA'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20102: Problem in loading Affected Circle data
ORA-06512: at "SRUSER.ADD_AFFECTEDCIRCLE", line 28
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

But what I need to show is like this

```
   ORA-20102: Circle Code is wrong or not available
   ORA-20101: Problem in loading Affected Circle data
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/errors.htm#i1871) has a third parameter which controls whether the exception replaces the current exception stack (the default behaviour) or adds to it.

> If you specify TRUE, PL/SQL puts error_code on top of the error stack.
>   Otherwise, PL/SQL replaces the error stack with error_code.

So if you pass it `TRUE` it will show both messages; in the call from your procedure:

```
...
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20101, 'Problem in loading Affected Circle data',
  TRUE);
END;
```

gives you the output:

```
BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20101: Problem in loading Affected Circle data
ORA-06512: at "SRUSER.ADD_AFFECTEDCIRCLE", line 13
ORA-20102: Circle Code is wrong or not available
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

---

To only show the messages and not the other stack information you'd need to manipulate the stack. [This article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2005/05-mar/o25plsql-093886.html) touches on how to use [`format_error_backtrace`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_util.htm#sthref11306) to extract the information you're interested in, but unfortunately the link to the `BT` package are dead. Some of the same ground [is covered here](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/b/weblog/archive/2012/10/19/exception-back-tracing.aspx). Essentially you need to parse the exception string into lines, and only display those that start with `ORA-20%`, I think.

But be careful about losing information that might actually be vital. In particular I'd suggest you only trap the specific errors you're looking for, not `OTHERS` - leave that alone so you can deal with unexpected errors and don't hide something important.

Comment: This helps me lot. can't we able to remove other stack information like "ORA-06512: at "SRUSER.ADD_AFFECTEDCIRCLE", line 13"