# ORA-20001, ORA-06512: at line 59 ORA-06512 exception error

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

Here is part of my PL/SQL block where I define an exception. It runs okay when my data does not contain any exceptions but generate the error message when there are exceptions. The error message is as follows:"ORA-20001: Invalid score change.
ORA-06512: at line 59
ORA-06512: at line 73"

I am wondering what went wrong with it. Can anyone help me out here? Thanks.

```
begin

   if (newpoints<0 or newpoints>maximumpoints) then 
            raise invalid_score_change;
         end if; 
exception 
      when invalid_score_change then
         raise_application_error(-20001,'Invalid score change.');
end;
```

Comment: What behavior do you actually expect from your programming?

Comment: That's doing exactly what you told it to do. What is the problem?

Comment: I simplified my code above. Generally, I want to raise an exception error message when newpoints is less then 0 or larger than maximumpoints. But it has error message ORA-06512.

Comment: It has your ORA-20001 first. The rest is the exception stack showing where it was raised.

Comment: If you have a calling block and want to hide the stack trace for some reason then [the second half of this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18056321/266304) might give some pointers. I thought I'd written an example but can't find it. [The article it links to](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2005/05-mar/o25plsql-093886.html) explains what you are seeing, which is expected, and usually desirable. Reporting or storing an expected exception like this appears to be may be a legitimate reason to use `format_error_stack` as the article shows.

Answer (score 0):

Even though as others have suggested, the program is doing exactly as you have told it to - your problem is that you have an unbound exception which is causing the outer ORA-06512 which you want to remove. Your problem is that you have raised and exception without a handler for it. If you do not want to see the ORA-06512 message you need to handle the exception like this by wrapper another exception handler around it - BTW this in my opinion is not good practice but I'm just answering your question.

```
begin
    begin

       if (newpoints<0 or newpoints>maximumpoints) then 
            raise invalid_score_change;
       end if; 
     exception 
       when invalid_score_change then
       raise_application_error(-20001,'Invalid score change.');
       --- you are now throwing and unhandled exception to be caught by the next handler below
    end;
 exception
     when others then
       ----- do something
     null; -- just to get it to compile
 end;
```